# How would you create a shaman by multi-classing druid and cleric?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, cleric, multi-classing

So I am planning on playing a shaman like character, slight WoW-inspiration. I was thinking a dwarf stone focused shaman, using spells such as stoneskin, conjure elemental and generally just hitting things with his hammer. Anyway I was thinking of going as a Cleric forge domain to get access to searing smite for powering up my hammer, and then going druid of the land (mountain) the rest of the way for spells.

The druid of the moon elemental wildshape would be really cool but the theme of the character is more using the elements to enhance my abilities so I wasn't really planning on using wildshape all that much. So being a dwarf and connected to the mountains and stone specifically I like the idea of wearing metal armor. However going druid that might be a problem.

So my question is how would you solve this? Allowing metal armor and the cost of no wildshape while using it? Disallowing it at all? Can I take levels of different classes and simply calling myself a shaman and just avoiding the druid metal armor thing all together? Maybe altering wildshape to only allow changing into elementals using the same restrictions for wildshaping at the cost of always using your two charges? Something else maybe?

I've taken a quick peek at ironwood but that doesn't quite get the look I'm going for.

I am primarily focused on the spells from the druid so that's probably where most of my levels would go. Ideally I would roll up a cleric forge domain or war domain with their spell list swapped with the druid list including the spells from circle of the land (mountain).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour].  There is a lot to consider here; have you discussed with your DM about modifying the class features and spell lists?  What do you want to achieve with your character?  If the armor restriction is a problem, have you looked at the other cleric domains?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Unfortunately, "survey"-type questions like "How would you do this?" aren't really a good fit for this site, as there's no way to choose a single best answer; every answer is equally valid. However, you may be able to rephrase this in a manner that is answerable on the site.